# Is there a way to use Firebase with Stripe without extra Server?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I built my app with Firebase and everything works nicely. But now I need to charge user like Uber style (using Stripe Connect or marketplace solution). Stripe require server setup to CHARGE user. Angular can only generate Stripe token. Can I use Firebase (or Firebase Queue) to do the CHARGE user part so I do not need to create a new nodejs server to just insert couple lines of Stripe codes? If so, could anyone tell me how to do that or example? Thanks!

Comment: Don't think so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase+stripe-payments

Comment: I think we can do it using firebase functions @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Back when Hugh asked this question, Cloud Functions wasn't available on Firebase yet. But that is indeed a valid option nowadays. There's even [example of integrating Stripe on Firebase's Github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe). Can you add that as an answer? Ping me again and I'll upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can considering using a serverless solution such as AWS Lambda or Webtask.io. This enables you to upload a minimal set of scripts that handles the backend processing for charging the customer and creating an entry in Firebase.